# CSS Grid not converting from a single column to a single row as a result of a media query

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, css-grid

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>

</div>


.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: space-around;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 70vh;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, minmax(auto, 30rem)) 1fr;
    background: pink;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column: 2/4;
    justify-content: center;
    background: cyan;
  }
}
```

I've created a column that contains three circles in it, each stacked on top of the other in a column, which all looks fine when the screen is narrow. But when the browser is widened and I add a media query for when the screen gets wider than 1100px, I want the *column* of circles to flip to become a single *row* of circles.

But when I do this using CSS Grid, it doesn't work, and two circles appear on one row, and the third circle appears below the first circle on a second row. You can see it at https://codepen.io/HorrieGrump/pen/ZEKxJgv

I *can* get it to work if I use flexbox instead (as shown below) by swapping out the current **.wrapper** block in CSS and using this new one with flexbox, but I'd like to know if it's possible to use CSS Grid instead of flexbox to do this.

Can someone please let me know how to get the media query to flip the column into a single row using CSS Grid – and not have to resort to flexbox?

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    background: cyan;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your media query for .wrapper

```
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    grid-column: 2/4;
    background: cyan;
  }
```

Comment: V. helpful solution – thanks, @rivrug. But it seems counterintuitive, at least to me in my  ignorance, because I would have thought that setting **grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, minmax(auto, 30rem)) 1fr;** would have made the middle column a single, undifferentiated area where the 3 circles would play nicely. But, as you point out, it looks I need to again divide it into 3 columns to accommodate the 3 circles. What do you think is best practice – use Grid like this to distribute the circles, or use flexbox?

Comment: For something simple like this, I would stick to flexbox. But if you are still planning on adding more code, then maybe consider a 3x3 grid and have the circles in the middle row/column.